# How can I open "view more actions" of a document added in a new tab in the start workflow form in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I hope can you help me... I need open document details (View more Actions)of the documents added to a new workflow in a new tab, actually the document details open in the same tab and when i try back to the start workflow form, i have start all newly. Thank you.
P.D: Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you trying to do this with?

Answer (score 2):

In the share form control named **packageitems.ftl** just change this piece:

```html
<#local documentLinkResolver>
  function(item) { return item.isContainer ? Alfresco.util.siteURL("folder-details?nodeRef=" + item.nodeRef, { site: item.site }) : Alfresco.util.siteURL("document-details?nodeRef=" + item.nodeRef, { site: item.site }); }
</#local>
```

To:

```html
<#local documentLinkResolver>
  function(item) { return item.isContainer ? Alfresco.util.siteURL("folder-details?nodeRef=" + item.nodeRef, { site: item.site }) : Alfresco.util.siteURL("document-details?nodeRef=" + item.nodeRef, { site: item.site },target="_blank"); }
</#local>
```

if you get an issue with the comma in the Alfresco.util.siteURL just change that to +. Or store it in a variable and add a store.

Be sure to make this your own custom packageitems control, in another folder structure and where needed add it to the share config.